# Azure function with Service Bus trigger calls the namespace with no reason

Tags: azure, request, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have the following code:

```
[FunctionName("myFunc")]
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myQueue", Connection = "ConnectionString")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
}
```

It is published in an Azure Function App that has Managed Identity configured to a namespace. The app shows no executions (no messages have been sent to the queue/namespace):
[image]

Yet, at the same time the namespace shows it has received requests:
[image]

The namespace has no other queues and NOTHING else connects/accesses/requests the namespace and queue. Also, if the function app is stopped the requests stop, as well.

I'm trying to figure out why would the function app send requests to the namespace (and so many) when it wasn't even triggered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one reason that I can think of is that it could be monitoring the queue length.
Azure Functions will auto-scale up/down based on the number of messages in the queue after all.

Comment: To add to what @juunas said, there's also a simpler reason - pulling for messages. Functions, just as any other receiver, has to get the messages to process those. The only way to receive with ASB is to periodically pull for new messages.

Comment: Ah, did SB also use polling? I know Storage queues use polling but wasn't aware SB did as well :)

Comment: Technically, it's a **long-pulling** where a request is made and ends when a message is delivered or the operation timeouts. Still, it generates requests.

Comment: Both Sean and Juunas are correct; the scale controller is requesting metrics to participate in scale out/in decisions and the trigger informs the service it is ready to receive a message and waits until the credit expires, then sends another.  Not quite the same as Storage queues since they're HTTP not AMQP but conceptually very similar.  For those interested, the `ServiceBusListener` is what is polling, the `ServiceBusScaleMonitor` is computing metrics.   Both here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus/src/Listeners

Comment: @JesseSquire, this is horrible! The service bus namespace is charged on the amount of requests made, I would expect a ServiceBusTrigger to register a webhook with the queue so that the function be invoked when a message is added! If it just sends a 100 requests an hour, I'd be better off setting a TimerTrigger! Am I wrong? Also, why don't these count as function executions? I doubt they can run without the function, yet it seems I would get incorrect statistics on usage and billing for the function app.

Comment: This isn't a good forum for long-form discussion, but a couple of follow-ups.   The bindings are intentionally biased towards ensuring processing throughput and are likely not the best approach for very low volume cost control.   Service Bus does not offer web hooks, but you could achieve via Event Grid.   You'd be trading off responsiveness and coordinated scaling for reducing operations.   More information: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/event-grid/handler-service-bus

Comment: With respect to billing, assuming a standard tier, the first 13 million operations are free (the next 87M cost $.080).   In a 30-day month, if the scale controller requests metrics every second (which it does not, but I don't know the exact duration) and no messages are available to be read, the basic infrastructure will generate ~2.6 million operations, falling well below the initial charge threshold and leaving ~10M operations free for send/receive.  For basic tier, that would incur roughly a $0.15 monthly cost.  More information: https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/details/service-bus/